# Access 2010 Form Data Filtering Error In Navigation Window

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a form based on my transactions table, which has an 'account' combo box in the header to filter the transactions based on the selected accounts.

I used the new Actions (or Macro Actions) to setup the filter, which is basically:

1. `SetTempVar (Name: CurrentAccountId, Expression: [screen].[activecontrol]`
2. `ApplyFilter (Where: [Account] = [TempVars]![CurrentAccountId]`
3. `RemoveTempVar (Name: CurrentAccountId)`

This works very well if the form is loaded by itself, but as soon as I load the form in a navigation form (form with tabs on top and left) and I use the filter again I get the following error:

> The action or method is invalid because the form or report isn't bound to a table or query.

I checked online and some posts refer to the SelectObject action which didn't work. It threw another error. Here's what I did (I added a step before step 2 above):

1. `SelectObject (Object Type: form, Object Name: Transactions List, In Database Window: no)`

The error I received is:

> The object Transactions List isn't open.

The combo box list with my accounts is on the form where this filtering should occur, so:

1. I'm not sure why my first approach works in the form window when it's loaded by itself
2. Why would it throw an error in a navigation window

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try using [OpenForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238021(v=office.12)) to open the "Transactions List" form object before [Selecting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214072(v=office.12).aspx) it?